# Reduce Image Size(not dimensions) in Laravel before uploading to S3 Bucket

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I want to reduce Image size (not dimensions) before uploading the image to S3 Bucket in Laravel, Is there any way I can do it?

I tried a lot to find some solutions and also tried my best but nothing happened and none of the solutions worked for me.

This is how I'm uploading an image to S3 Bucket without reducing size:-

**Code:-**

```
$file = $request->file('file');
$file_name = 'user-id-'.session('login_user_id').'_'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$target_dir = "assets/images/";
$target_file = $target_dir .$file_name;
$target_file = str_replace(' ','-',$target_file);
$disk = 's3';
Storage::disk($disk)->put($target_file, file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]), 'public')
```

Any help will be appreciated **Thanks**

**PS:** I found some solutions talking about reducing image dimensions but I want to reduce image size
e.g from 1000KB to size < 1000KB

Comment: It seems you're looking to reduce the image quality. Try searching for [`reduce image quality php`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reduce+image+quality+php) and see if any of those solutions apply for you.

Comment: @AlexHowansky thanks for your time, the link given is not suitable for me, 1-you can see it is not for the s3 bucket because uploading to S3  is different from simple uploading to our server, 2- I want to reduce size before uploading but is reducing and uploading at once.

Answer (score -3):

You can use [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) laravel package. Using this package you can resize the size in dimension  or size.

Comment: it is to resize dimensions not to reduce image size, dimensions !== size